# How should you use C++11 Regex to create variables from a table stored in a text file?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This may be a fairly trivial question but I am confused about how Regex works in C++. I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
Weapons:    Cost  Damage  Armor
Dagger        8     4       0
Shortsword   10     5       0
Warhammer    25     6       0
Longsword    40     7       0
Greataxe     74     8       0
```

I want to store each weapons Name, Cost, Damage and Armor in a Struct. I tried to do that with the following code:

```
regex rule("(\\w+)\s(\\w+)\s(\\w+)\s(\\w+)");
smatch match;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (regex_match(lines[i], match, rule)) {
        struct Weapon Weapon;
        Weapon.Name = match[1];
        Weapon.Cost = stoi(match[2], NULL, 10);
        Weapon.Damage = stoi(match[3], NULL, 10);
        Weapon.ArmorValue = stoi(match[4], NULL, 10);
        Weapons.push_back(Weapon);
    }
}
```

However the if statement is always returning false.

Am I using the Regex Rule wrongly?

How should I be using Regex to store the data from that table in a struct?

Comment: \ within string literals need to be escaped, so you need \\ everywhere. Better to use raw string literals `rule(R"((\\w+)\s(\\w+)\s(\\w+)\s(\\w+))")`

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the answer! So with raw string literals I can just use single backslashes and don't need to escape them? (Just wondering since you still have the \w character escaped)

Comment: Oops, sorry, wasn't paying attention to what you actually trying to parse, just noticed that you didn't have `\s` escaped in the original. You don't need to escape any of backslashes. `rule(R"((\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+))")`

Comment: If you don't need to use regexs, you can just read the file line by line with an `ifstream`. Like `in >> name >> cost >> damage >> armor;`

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the regex could be tweaked to allow spaces and digits in the weapon name.  It'd be tricky I think.

Comment: Praetorian, Thanks for the help, I also needed a + after the \s to get it working! Both your raw string literal solution and Malin's solution worked great!. @BaummitAugen I could have used ifstream but just wanted to try out Regex so I can learn it, thanks anyway!.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I think your regex should look more like this :
    (\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)

You just lost spaces there.

Now just iterate over array and remember that <s>first</s> zero-th match is 
"Dagger        8     4       0" (with spaces)

Edit:
next matches would be as follows:

match[1] = "Dagger"
match[2] = "8"
match[3] = "4"
match[4] = "0"

and here is my test code :

```
std::string data = "Dagger        8     4       0";
std::regex rule("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)");
std::smatch match;
if (regex_match(data, match, rule)) {
    std::cout << match[0] << std::endl << match[1] << match[2] << match[3] << match[4] << std::endl;
}
```

Edit 2 :
Personally I would rather use \d instead of \w and here is why :

Lets assume that one of lines looks like this :
"Dagger        3      3       word"

using \w would take 'word' and regex_match returns true now assuming that your Weapon.ArmorValue is some kind of numerical data this char* would be converted to this numerical value and data would be not in a good state.(*)

However using \d makes your regex_match returning false because 'word' is not a number.
Ofcourse I assume that those are integers ( doubles and float would need regex like \d+.\d+)
Thus your regex would look like this now :

> (\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)

(*)Or even worse - it might raise some exception which may cause your program to stop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, got it working! Out of interest why would you use \d instead?